# Xamarin studio - Monotouch framework not installed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Since some days, Xamarin.iOS started to do weird things: It is refusing to build on my Mac machine with the following error for all iOS related projects:

'MonoTouch Framework' not installed

On my Visual Studio machine, it's sometimes not copying all files and therefore failing the build. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, I updated everything to the latest version :)

Comment: Okay, but that doesnt solve the problem that it does not build on xamarin studio, which I need to generate the ipa file, right?